# php code if then else tag

Tags: php, html, web

I am quite new to php world. I searched this site for the specific thing I was looking for but could not find it.

Question: I have a page where I want a tag such as "User = " so if there is a url that has index.php?u=Joe then i want the "User = Joe" to show up on the page for that user.

Now I have came as far as that point without a problem. My Issue is that I want to still show something if somebody goes to the index.php without the ?u=user value.

For example: if there is nothing in the url then I want the page to say "User = Unknown".

I know this can be done with an if statement but I need some help with it I cannot find the right concept.

Thanks.

Comment: Surf for php s $_GET variable...

Comment: Thank you everyone for quick replies! My Issue is fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isset()` to test if the parameter variable has been provided.

```
if (isset($_GET['u'])) {
    $user = $_GET['u'];
} else {
    $user = "Unknown";
}

echo "User = $user";
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to check if the value is set with [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET["u"]) && $_GET["u"] != ""){
  $var = $_GET["u"];
} else{
  $var = "Joe";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answers, but I prefer `array_key_exists` over `isset`.

```
if (array_key_exists('u', $_GET))
```

Reason being that `array_key_exists` is specific for arrays and has less 'magical' exceptions than `isset`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `filter_input($input_type,$input_var_name)` to get the value of the variable. This is because this returns false if the variable cannot be found. If you pull it from an array, it will throw an Error. You could use something like this:

```
$user = filter_input(INPUT_GET,'u');
$user = !isset($user) ? 'Unknown' : $user;
```

However, you should encapsulate this in a function so that you do not have to rewrite this every time you need the username. In fact, if you need the username to persist across multiple pages, I recommend using cookies.

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick: Fast and easy..

```
if($_GET['u']!=''){
    echo 'user = '.$_GET['u'];  //  The parameter has been set, and is not empty.
} else {
    echo 'Unknown user';    //  The parameter has not even been set. So the value has no impact, and is not checked.
}
```

Comment: Watch out, this code will work but it will create an error in your error_log file. You have to use isset() instead.

Comment: What would be the error?

Comment: I tested your code and this is what I got in my error.log file: `PHP Notice:  Undefined index: u in /home/public/test.php on line 3`

Comment: Okey. That's just because I'm checking a variable that hasn't been set yet. I don't think that's a big deal. But of course the `isset()` function removes that issue though... You could also remove that notice by setting the variable first (`$_GET['u']=''`), which I don't find necessary since it's just a notice. But yeah. using isset() is not hard to write ;)

Comment: Yeah, I know, that's not a big deal, but I had a problem in the past related to this issue. My error.log file became so huge that my server went down. I'm not sure why, but I cleaned up error.log and everything went fine after that. Also, if you're like me and you check your error.log file once in a while for debugging, it's nice to get rid of useless notices ;)

Comment: Yes. I agree. If it gets too big, it takes time to open, read/write, save and close...